# Syntax for multiple positive lookaheads in JavaScript regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to include two positive lookaheads in one regex. Here's the problem I'm working on as an example.

```
(?=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20}
```

This is what I'm trying to match:

- 0-20 characters
- one or more letter anywhere
- one or more number anywhere
- only letters and numbers allowed

When I do this with only one lookahead, it works, but as soon as I add the other, it breaks. What's the correct syntax for two lookaheads?

Comment: How about this `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20}`?

Comment: Side note, that doesn't allow for underscores. You need `[a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,20}`, which is synonymous to `\w{0,20}`.

Comment: I realized I forgot to include underscores in my original regex, so I took it out of the list of requirements. I'll use \w in the final version. Thanks!

Comment: @revo Fails where a pattern of `\d{20}[a-zA-Z]` matches (i.e. if the lookahead looks more than 20 ahead to report positively, it's false in terms of the specification. Hard to fix since variable-length lookarounds are a pain for regex engines. (`(?=.*{0,19}[a-zA-Z])(?=.*{0,19}\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20}` should work if it compiles)

Comment: @AlexR Yes, add a `$` at the end of regex.

Comment: @revo I elaborated on the effects of the different approaches to fix the issue :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Lookaheads** are like wanders! You limited the domain of looks at the first place which won't fulfill the requirement. You may use a greedy dot `.*` (or lazy `.*?`) regex to allow a lookahead to look for each requirement.

As @AlexR mentioned in comments I modify the RegEx a little bit:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,20}$
```

*By the way, you forgot matching underscores, which I added.*

The above is almost equal to:

```
^(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=\D*\d)\w{1,20}$
```

Answer (score 2):

A problem with @revos answer occurs when the input is too long: `01234567890123456789A` passes both lookaheads and the final check. A fixed version either checks for end-of-string with `^` and `$` or uses variable-length lookaround (or both):

```
^(?=.{0,19}[a-zA-Z])(?=.{0,19}[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20}$ // (1), (1*) without ^
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20}$
(?=.{0,19}[a-zA-Z])(?=.{0,19}[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20} // (2)
```

Only the latter will allow text around the specified string. Omitting the `^` in the former variants will allow the password to be prefixed, i.e.

```
Input            : "Password1 = ASDF0123"
Matches with (1) : none
Matches with (1*): "ASDF0123"
Matches with (2) : "Password1", "ASDF0123"
```

Comment: You bring up a really interesting case. Since I'll be using this in a form, I can add a maxlength="20" attribute to the input tag. I wouldn't have realized I needed that without this.

Comment: @Qaz I would still recommend using a stricter regex, since a tool like FireBug allows editing client-side so you can never be sure your form POST (or GET) is sane since it is under control of your (possibly malicious) client.

Comment: No matter how exact I make the regex, it's dead easy to edit it on the client side- I'm putting it right in the HTML! (<input pattern="regexHere">) Don't worry, though. This is just for the benefit of the users so they know if their passwords fit the rules. I'll do a serious check on the client side. Also don't worry about how insecure the password rules are; this is not for production.

Comment: @Qaz Okay you didn't mention the regex was client-side anyways. I thought you planned on using it server-side for validation (wich then should be one of my methods, depending on your needs).

Comment: Yep, I'll definitely use a regex client-side, and maybe some other checks as well. I should have remembered JS wasn't just for the client side and mentioned specifically that this is going on both ends.